# How can I make an 'overwrite' option with argparse easily?

Tags: python, argparse

Python `argparse` supports [`FileType`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) for reading and writing files. But it does not support `overwrite` option itself. I have to close it and open it again with `w` option, like below;

```
args = SomeParser().parse_args()
foo = args.infile.read()

# Do something in foo  

args.infile.close()
with open(args.infile.name, 'w') as f:
    f.write(foo)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: The choice between `r/w` for mode is builtin to the `argparse` code (look it up in the `argparse.py` file).  For more control on the file, I advise skipping `FileType`.  Just accept the file name as a string, and do your own `with open`.  Or write your own `FileType` class.

Comment: How would you expect this `overwrite` option to work? Stating the expected calling signature or API might help others provide an answer.  Because right now what you are doing seems pretty simple to me.

Comment: @SethMMorton You're right. It must be better not to have an ambiguous or implicit code here. Thanks.